# Epoch date in the form 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I am new to SQL and have run into a problem. I want to have the epoch date i.e. 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z in this mentioned format.

I **cannot use it as a constant (i.e. '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')** for programming reasons. I need a statement that gives this as an output. I have used this:

```
select to_char(TRUNC(add_months(sysdate,-555),'MM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"') from dual;
```

But the only problem with this statement is it will not give me the date I want next month i.e. it is month specific it will only work for April 2016. But I need a the date to always remain 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

Thanks in advance for the help.

PS: I am using Oracle SQL Developer (if that matters).

Comment: Read [here about date format ISO 8601 in Oracle](https://orastory.wordpress.com/2007/05/15/dates-timestamps-and-iso-8601/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do:

```
select '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z' from dual;
```

Or if you want to have it processed for some reason, which seems like pointless overhead:

```
select to_char(date '1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"') from dual;
```

Either will give you the string you want. But it is a string, *not* a date. If you want it as a proper data type (which I don't think you do, but maybe this is for comparison) it needs to be a timestamp with time zone, which you can get with:

```
select timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this might not be the most elegent way but it is a way that will work:

```
select regexp_substr('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z','^....................',1,1) from dual;
```